# how generate this address and how i can change this address

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

this address how generate and how i can specify this address

im new in blockchain please explain for me. what is this

[image: deployed addresses]

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is the deployment of a smart contract.
When a contract is deployed, the address of the contract is determined by the following values:

1. The address of the sender of the transaction containing the contract creation
2. The current nonce value (a counter that shows how many times the sender has sent a transaction)

Those values are packed as byte-arrays into an array [bytearray_sender, bytearray_nonce] and are encoded using RLP. The result of the RLP encoding is hashed using Keccak256. Finally, you get the address of the contract by taking the rightmost 20 byte of the resulting hash.

The hash-function which creates the hash containing the address, in this case keccak256, has to be cryptographically secure. One property of cryptographically secure hashing functions is, that you are not able to reconstruct the input to the hashing function which leads to the hash. In other words, you cannot select an address by your own since you don't know which input to the hashing function creates the hash containing the address.

Comment: this project about token sale but i buy token with another account not transfer ethereum to my account
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xcc173279dfc00859e2687cdb5a5dc63eca478597